# How do I push only one table from my development database to my production database in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to push my "defaults" table from my development database to my production database.

Any rake command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'll make the trick:

> A simple database agnostic import/export app to transfer data to/from
>   a remote database.

https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps

> when you want to transfer a list of tables

```
$ taps push postgres://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost/dbname http://httpuser:httppassword@example.com:5000 --tables logs,tags
```

Comment: I see this is what heroku uses. That looks good, now i just have to figure out how to configure it. Thanks!